# How do i show object only once in foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, foreach

i have a few object and i want them to be sorted in clusters. My current code has above every  it's cluster but i want it to be shown only once for each cluster.

```
var Applications =



 [

{cluster: 'WS', ID: '3113', Name: 'management'},

{cluster: 'WS', ID: '3116', Name: 'Calculator'},

{cluster: 'MIS', ID: '113', Name: 'Mandate'},

{cluster: 'MIS', ID: '116', Name: 'Currency'},
]

var content = "";
Applications.forEach(generateRow);



function generateRow(item, index, arrays) {

    var columns = "";
    var clusterhead ;


    clusterhead = columns + "<td colspan='3'>" + item.cluster + "</td>"  ;
    columns = columns + "<td onclick='testfn(\"" + index + "\", this)'>" +  item.ID + "</td>";
    columns = columns + "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>";
    columns = columns + "<td>" + "<a href='https:" + item.ID + "/ApplicationDetails/'>map</a>" + "</td>";

    content =  content +  "<tr>" + clusterhead + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + columns + "</tr>";

}
```

// Right now the outcome is this.

```
      WS
3113 managment appmap
      WS
3116 Calculator appmap

I want to look like this

      WS
3113 managment appmap
3116 Calculator appmap
```

Comment: there's difference between the input and output you show. The ids from the input are nowhere to be found in the output. please provide a more coherent example

Comment: Ok i corrected it.

Comment: It will be a good idea to map the array to a more useful shape. Please provide the way you call generateRow() in your code. I assume it's in a forEach loop?

Comment: sorry i thought i had the forEach there my bad.

Comment: not sure what the last line of the function does... maybe should have posted an exmaple of the rendered html. Anyway - I posted an answer, let me know if it does it for you.

Comment: What about multiple clusters in output ? For example the `MIS` cluster. Where should it be ? Bellow the `WS` records (new TR) ? On they're right (same TR with row spans) ?

Comment: Just to clarify I'm making a table .

Comment: Cluster should only be displayed once and under should be all the info like ID name etc. under all info with the same cluster should start a new cluster with all info from object with same cluster.  WS and Mis should only be displayed once. Currently Ws is shown above every row i want it to be shown once and it should be the first Row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Applications = [
  { cluster: 'WS', ID: '3113', Name: 'management' },
  { cluster: 'WS', ID: '3116', Name: 'Calculator' },
  { cluster: 'MIS', ID: '113', Name: 'Mandate' },
  { cluster: 'MIS', ID: '116', Name: 'Currency' },
]

let printedClusters = [];
var content = "";

Applications.forEach(generateRow);
$('#tbl').append(content)

function generateRow(item, index, arrays) {

  var columns = "";
  var clusterhead = "";

  if (!printedClusters.includes(item.cluster)) {
    clusterhead = columns + "<td colspan='3'>" + item.cluster + "</td>";
    printedClusters.push(item.cluster);
  }

  columns = columns + "<td onclick='testfn(\"" + index + "\", this)'>" + item.ID + "</td>";
  columns = columns + "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>";
  columns = columns + "<td>" + "<a href='https:" + item.ID + "/ApplicationDetails/'>map</a>" + "</td>";

  content = content + "<tr>" + clusterhead + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + columns + "</tr>";

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't generate anything just blank screen.

Comment: @Smytt how about you output that code on the HTML section of your snippet. It looks ok, but it's not helpful in the console.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a temporary dictionary to sort them, and then to display the data of your dict.

```
myDict = [];
data = [{'cluster': 1, 'data': 'yes'}, {'cluster': 2, 'data': 'no'}, {'cluster': 1, 'data': 'yes'}];

data.forEach(elem => {
    if(myDict[elem.cluster])
        myDict[elem.cluster].push(elem.data);
    else
        myDict[elem.cluster] = [elem.data];
})
```

This way, the data is finally sorted so you can display it the way you want

Comment: Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qaxkw0sb/1/
Open the console to see the output